# .NET C# Serialport not working as it should

Tags: c#, .net, port

I am having problems with doing stuff on my serialport communication. 
The issue is that the port is open but when I check if(_cc.port.IsOpen) nothing happens and it jumps to else where it will try open the port. Well, the port cannot be opened as it says it's already open.

COMcon.CS

```
private void connectSerial(string indata, string password) 
        {
            port = new SerialPort(indata, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
            string time = dt.ToShortTimeString();

            try 
            {
                port.Open();
                port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);

                if (port.IsOpen)
                {
                    port.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
                    port.WriteLine("no");
                    port.WriteLine("enable");

                    if (password != String.Empty)
                    {
                        port.WriteLine(password);
                    }

                    port.WriteLine("terminal length 0");
                    port.WriteLine("config terminal");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine("Error" + ex);  }
```

CommandManager.CS

```
 public bool rCommand(string command) 
        {
            try
            {
                if (_cc.port.IsOpen)
                {
                    _cc.port.WriteLine(command);
                    log.WriteLine(command);
                    return true; // True?
                }
                else
                {
                    _cc.port.Open();
                    log.Write(logger.logHandler("CODE1"));

                    if (_cc.port.IsOpen)
                        log.Write(logger.logHandler("CODE2"));
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex); log.Write("Error: " + ex); return false; } // Error
        }
```

Comment: What is the relation of your comcon.cs and CommandManager.cs? Based on the error you have already opened the port. Possible reason why _cc.port.IsOpen returns false is that it may be using a different instance of the open serial port even if they are both pointing to the same com port.

Comment: COMcon is having the instance of the serialport as public so I can access it from other classes, though, that does not seem to work... So it should be using the same instance

Comment: Can you show how you are passing the same instance of comcon to other classes? Also how the port of comcon is turned to _cc in commandmanager.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/UBFX0sKR
http://pastebin.com/N7YmPHWU

I checked to see if there would be any difference to have the rCommand class in the same as the instance of SerialPort but that didn't make any difference.

Comment: Do you have any clues?